# Identifying exact component versions of a build artifact

Tags: maven, build-process, hudson, jenkins, artifacts

How can I set up a Jenkins based build process (using Artifactory Pro for artifact storage) of a fairly complex product so that the version/revision of each of its components can be easily identified?

Some of these components might have been created from other components (essentially, an aggregation), so those sub-component revisions would need to be identifiable in turn.

I'd rather not build and the complete (large) product all the time, archiving its sources along with it, instead using previously created artifacts. During development, they'd likely have a SNAPSHOT version that is used for a while.

When, during testing, an issue is discovered, how can I trace it back to the exact source control revisions of each of the completed product's components for analysis? *We don't use SVN for everything, and there's no Jenkins plugin for the other VCS.*

---

Some of what we do is based on Maven, but solutions should be flexible enough to not require a Maven project in Jenkins.

Comment: What kind of VCS are you using? Jenkins has many plugins for VCS's. And why don't you use SVN (or any other VCS) for all your stuff ? May be you could use the JENKINS ID (Job Id etc.) to identify artifacts but you have to put this information into your build (Maven).

Comment: @khmarbaise We will be migrating to SVN later this year. Our current proprietary VCS does not have a Maven module. If not possible otherwise, consider providing an answer that requires SVN.

Comment: Which VCS ? ClearCase ? PVCS ?

Comment: @khmarbaise MKS Integrity. I just learned that there actually *is* a plugin, but I'm not sure using it makes sense at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [maven-buildnumber-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/) to get the revision number from Subversion and put this information into the MANIFEST file.

```
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
              </manifest>
              <manifestEntries>
                  <buildNumber>${buildNumber}</buildNumber>
              </manifestEntries>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The following snippet will call the buildNumber plugin and use a different string for the version if no SVN working copy exists. May be this can be replaced by the Job_ID of jenkins etc.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-beta-4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>create</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <revisionOnScmFailure>git</revisionOnScmFailure>
      <doCheck>false</doCheck>
      <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
      <getRevisionOnlyOnce>true</getRevisionOnlyOnce>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: What about components that are not Java based? Some of these are, for example, generated resources in a very specific format, that might not allow inclusion of build information directly (metadata in the repository at best).

Comment: But you have to package those resources in any kind?